# How to run windows command prompt within a .NET appliaction?

Tags: c#, .net

I am making a .NET application that I need to run the windows command prompt within that application.

Is this possible? If yes then how?

I need to make something that looks like the image shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4L15.jpg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands

Comment: Why don't you just have it run the console application instead?

Comment: Don't fix cmd if it ain't broke.

Comment: The real question is how do you run a command prompt within a command prompt application?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the System.Diagnostics.Process class.
Start cmd with this class and redirect the Streams.
Then you can draw a bitmap with a white font and show it to the user.

Anyway, like Ramhound i would directly show the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx):

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe");
```